# OpenCV: Understanding Kernel

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

My book says this about the Image Kernel concept in OpenCV

> When a computation is done over a pixel neighborhood, it is common to
>   represent this with a kernel matrix. This kernel describes how the
>   pixels involved in the computation are combined in order to obtain the
>   desired result.

In image blur techniques, we use the kernel size.

```
cv::GaussianBlur(inputImage,outputImage,Size(1,1),0,0)
```

So, if I say the kernel size is `Size(1,1)` does that mean the kernel got only 1 pixel?

Please have a look at the following image

[image]

In here, what's the Kernel size? `Size(3,3)` ? If I say size `Size(1,1)` in this image, does that mean the kernel got only 1 pixel and the pixel value is 0 (The first value in the image)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image you post is a 3x3 kernel, which would be specified by `cv::Size(3,3)`. You are correct in saying that `cv::Size(1,1)` corresponds to a single pixel, but saying "`cv::Size(1,1)`" in reference to the image is not meaningful. A 1x1 kernel would simply have the value `[1]`.

Answer (score 9):

The kernel size in the example image you gave is 3-by-3 (`Size(3,3)`), yes. A kernel size of 1-by-1 *is* valid, although it wouldn't be very interesting.

The generic name for the operation being performed by `GaussianBlur` is a *convolution*.

The `GaussianBlur` function is creating a Gaussian kernel, which is basically a matrix that represents how you should combine a window of n-by-n pixels to get a single pixel value (using a Gaussian-shaped blurring pattern in this case).

A kernel of size 1-by-1 can't do anything other than scalar multiplication of an image; that is, convolution by the 1-by-1 matrix `[c]` is just `c * inputImage`.

Typically, you'll want to choose a n-by-n Gaussian kernel that satisfies:

- spread of Gaussian (i.e. standard deviation or variance) such that it blurs the amount you want

  - larger number means more blurring; smaller number means less blurring
- choose n sufficiently large as to not truncate the Gaussian too close to the mode

Links:

- [Convolution (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)
- [Gaussian blur (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur)

  - [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur#Sample_Gaussian_matrix) in particular

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. Special thanks for the explanation about the GaussianBlur. +1 from me :)

Comment: @Knight Not entirely clear to me why the other answer got the special check mark - whatever floats your boat.

Comment: "Larger Number Means More Blur" - I noticed it. But in opencv official examples they loop for 31 times! http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html#smoothing
Any idea about why they just simply don't use a big kernal size instead of looping? Even the size is edited inside the loop, it can be easily blured by giving a big size like Size(21,21)

Comment: @Knight In that example the reason they're looping is just because the want to show the effect of increasing the amount of blur. Each iteration of the loop does more blurring than the previous.

Answer (score 1):

This image is a kernel and it's size is 3x3. Kernels are applied to image by multiplying corresponding pixel values and getting sum of 9 results. This is called convolution / filtering in literature. You can look at following resources for more information :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/filtops.htm
http://www.cse.usf.edu/~r1k/MachineVisionBook/MachineVision.files/MachineVision_Chapter4.pdf