# Why does erode give different results in C++ and Python in OpenCV 3?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

In Python I am using erode as follows:

```
result = cv2.erode(image, None)
```

While in C++ I am using it as:

```
cv::erode(image, result, cv::Mat());
```

However they are giving different results? Do they have different default in OpenCV3 between Python and C++

Comment: I only used opencv few times, but don't you need a kernel of at least 3x3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655962/opencv-understanding-kernel

Comment: You used None for python, and empty Mat for C++, both are wrong, so even they give you the same results, it still wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @TonyJ neither are wrong both give a result. However they give different results. I'm asking what default they correspond to.